# Reordering Modified QuerySet

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset

My database is set up with a list of cases with an ID from our ticketing system, a location, an assigned person and a short description taken from the ticket:

- Case

  - ID
  - Location
  - Assigned Person
  - Short Description
  - Status

Now to help better sort things, depending on certain status values, we change the QuerySet after querying it.

```
current_active = Case.objects.filter(queue_num=0,status__lt=6)
for item in current_active:
    if(item.location == 'NPH'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'NPH'
    elif(item.location == 'Bins'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'Bins'
    elif(item.status > '2' and item.status < '6'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'Pending'
```

I was wondering if there was any way to sort this new modified QuerySet.  We know it prints correctly, it just comes down to the sorting that gets messed up.

**UPDATE 2**

```
current_active = Case.objects.filter(queue_num=0,status__lt=6)
current_active_list = []
for item in current_active:
    number = item.id
    item.id = '%07d' % number
    phone = item.myneuname.phonenumber
    if(len(phone) > 7):
        formattedPhone = phone[:-10]+' ('+phone[-10:-7]+') '+phone[-7:-4]+'-'+phone[-4:]
        item.myneuname.phonenumber = formattedPhone
    if(item.location == 'NPH'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'NPH'
    elif(item.location == 'Bins'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'Bins'
    elif(item.status > '2' and item.status < '6'):
        item.assigned_tech = 'Pending'
    current_active_list.append(item)
current_active_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.assigned_tech)
```

While this is not idea and Django-style, this does work.  If you have the same issue and find a more reasonable way to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to reply.  Making a Python list seemed the only way possible without saving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're evaluating the queryset and then modifying some of the elements without saving, you need to avoid anything that goes back to the database and re-evaluates it. In your case, there's nothing wrong with simply ordering the list in Python - for example:

```
current_active.sort(key=lambda x: x.assigned_tech)
```

to sort by the `assigned_tech` field.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will just do the exact thing as order_by and ignore the new values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're talking about [order_by](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method of django's ORM

Comment: order_by works on the original query.  But if we run it after modifying the values, it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: how are you "modifying" the values of the query?

Comment: And then how do you run again the queryset?

Comment: We would try and order_by by doing `current_active.order_by('assigned_tech')` after the for loop

Comment: I assume you aren't using transactions or something like that, rigth?

Comment: For your answer, not you aren't using transactions http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Can you show us more code, maybe in the question or in dpaste.com

Comment: Well, that's the point. We don't want to save the value.  I was trying to see if there was a way to do it without saving the value.

Comment: Remeber that querysets are lazy: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Comment: That means, in a few words, you can't reorder the queryset without save the item.

Comment: Well, since they are lazy, isn't it actually being called when I am checking what the location and number values are?  If so, then current_active should contain all my data after the for loop.  Is there a way to sort a QuerySet after the query is performed?

Comment: In that case, I guess I might make another field for Second Location or something

Comment: when you iterate over a queryset, you evaluate it, that means, hit the database, when you change some data in the queyset, that, in some way is 'lost', but when you show the items in templates, again, the queryset is evaluated, i suggest you, make a list the the items of queryset, or maybe a dict and order it, something like list(queryset) and use the method sorted in that element http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: You have to make save if you wanna show data from a queryset sorted. do you understand me?

Comment: Yes, I understand.  We were hoping to avoid using a list.  We might just save the data then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would sort that same QuerySet based on your new property, but if you were to append each `item` into a new list (after assigning `assigned_tech` to each item), you could do something like this:

```
import operator
new_list.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('assigned_tech'))
```

And to reverse the sort order:

```
import operator
new_list.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('assigned_tech'), reverse=True)
```

But if you find a way to do it without creating a new list, that would obviously be better and I would love to see it.